# Midnight Commander — Multiple Selection

Tags: selection, midnight-commander

In MC I can copy the name of the current file from the list of files to the console pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Suppose I want several files to copy to console. Example: want to create `*.zip` with several files:

```
zip new_zip.zip a.txt b.txt c.txt 231202fkfo3f.txt
```

I can select several files with Insert (or equiv. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>). I want one shortcut to use after that for all those selected files names to go right to the console. Something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

What are the ways of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd>, it will paste the names of all the files you've tagged with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> or <kbd>Insert</kbd> to the command line.

Answer (score 1):

A similar built-in solution is available from the <kbd>F2</kbd> user menu. It is called "Do something on the tagged files", and runs the given command on the files one-by-one.

New commands could be added to this menu. It's a bit tricky solution, but it worked for me. (Subshell support is necessary.)

User menu config file is usually located at:

```
/etc/mc/mc.menu
```

My solution is based on "Do something on the tagged files". I've copied its lines and modified like this:

```
+ t t
p       Put selected files to history
    set %t
    while [ -n "$1" ]; do
      STR="$STR \\\"$1\\\""
      shift
    done
    bash -ic "history -s $STR" > /dev/null
```

First line means that it should be shown only if multiple files are selected. The second line contains a title and a shortcut inside user menu (<kbd>p</kbd>). After that comes a shell script which adds selected filenames to your history.

Add these lines to `mc.menu` and be aware of tabulation. First and second line has no tabulation, and the script is tabulated with TABs. Otherwise `mc` would not be able to parse it.

After that you should select some files and press <kbd>F2</kbd>. Press the newly added "Put selected files to history". Now they are added to the history, but it should be re-read to be used. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, and you should type `history -r` to command line. Finally you will find the selected filenames by pressing <kbd>UP</kbd> key.

An alternative solution could be used also. Perhaps it is easier to simply print the string to the terminal, and after that you can copy-paste it. Following script implements this:

```
+ t t
p       Print selected files to subshell
    set %t
    while [ -n "$1" ]; do
      STR="$STR \"$1\""
      shift
    done
    echo "$STR"
```